# Rails 4 - Exception notifier doesn't send email if error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I have a Rails 4 app and using the gem `exception_notification`. The gem is installed, in `config/environments/production.rb` is following:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
    :email => {
      :email_prefix => "[MyProj Error Report] ",
      :sender_address => %{"MyProj" <no-reply@myproj.com>},
      :exception_recipients => %w{info@myproj.com}
    }
```

`no-reply@myproj.com` email address doesn't exist, `info@myproj.com` is my real email address.

When an error will occur on production, I don't receive any email about it.

What other configuration information do I need to add?

**EDIT:**
`config/environments/production.rb`:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  MyApp::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
    :email => {
      :email_prefix => "[MyApp_Error] ",
      :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@myAppName.com>},
      :exception_recipients => %w{your_email_id@gmail.com}
    }
end
```

I modified the code with my real email addresses, but still no success. In log is nothing - when I want to fetched a record with a non-existing ID, like `website.com/articles/123345666777`, in the error log is only the following:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Article with 'id'=123345666777):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:175:in `set_article'
```

Comment: Did you have a look into your log file if there are any errors? Is sendmail configured on the server? Where do you host your application? Did you try to send a "normal" ActionMailer?

Comment: The log is empty (there's no message about sending an error email). The app is hosted on DigitalOcean. I am using `Devise` and when I generate there forgotten password, the email is sent out.

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` is a very special case (same for routing errors and some others). I would be surprised if this kind of exceptions triggered the `ExceptionNotifier` to send mails. In a production environment, Rails would handle this error by rendering the `404` (not found) page, instead of a `500` (server error) that would happen if Rails couldn't handle the exception.

And in fact, there is the option `ignore_exceptions` in `ExceptionNotifier` that includes this exception by default. Read more about the [`ignore_exceptions` option and its defaults](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#ignore-exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

**try to use this...with the AppName like this:-**

```
 MyAppName::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
   :email => {
     :email_prefix => "[MyApp_Error] ",
     :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@myAppName.com>},
     :exception_recipients => %w{your_email_id@gmail.com}
   }
```

Comment: thank you for your message, I tested it out but still no email arrived (log is empty as well - no message about sending an email out).